# else statement is not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, forms, if-statement

Ok, so I made this code:

```
Acum adaugati note si absente pentru&nbsp;<?php echo $numeleelevuluiales ?>, la materia <?php echo $numelemateriei ?> :
<br />
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit13']))
{
    ?>
    Adauga o nota noua:

    <form method="post" action="" name="form666">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
      <tr>

        <td  width="50">Nota: &nbsp;

        <select name="note">
    <option value="eroare">Alege nota</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td   width="50"> Ziua:&nbsp;
    <select name="ziua">
    <option value="eroare1">Alege ziua</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>

    </td>
    <td   width="50">Luna: &nbsp;
    <select name="luna">
    <option value="eroare2">Alege luna</option>

    <?php
    $lunile = "SELECT id, luni
        FROM luni";
    $qlunile = mysql_query($lunile);

    while($luniletabel = mysql_fetch_array($qlunile))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$luniletabel['id']."' name='luna'>" . $luniletabel['luni'] . "</option>";
    }
     ?>
    </select>

    </td></tr>

      </table> <br />
         <input type="submit" name="submit13" value="&nbsp;Adauga &nbsp;" >
         </form><br />
    <?php

}//sfarsit if
else
{
    if(!isset($_POST['submit333']))
    {
        if($_POST['note'] == 'eroare' || $_POST['ziua'] == 'eroare1' || $_POST['luna'] == 'eroare2' )
        {
            echo "EROARE!!! Nu ati ales toate campurile <br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Ati ales nota&nbsp;" .$_POST['note'].", in ziua&nbsp;" .$_POST['ziua']. ", si luna a " .$_POST['luna']. ".";
            ?><br />
            Daca datele sunt corecte, apasati butonul de mai jos pentru adaugarea in baza de date:


             <form method="post" action="" name="form666">
             <input type="submit" name="submit333" value="&nbsp;Adauga in baza de date&nbsp;" >
                 </form>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else // daca a fost apasat submit 333
    {
        $azi = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
        //
        $data_adaugare = $azi->format("Y-m-d");
        //
        // se adauga cele 2 zile
        //
        $termen = 2; // zile de modificare
        //
        $azi->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));
        //
        $data_expirarii = $azi->format("Y-m-d");

        $materianote = $_SESSION['materienote'];
        $id_note = $_POST['note'];
        $data_nota = $_POST['ziua'];
        $luna_nota = $_POST['luna'];
        echo $id_note;

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO note(id_elev, id_materie, id_note, data_nota, luna_nota, data_adaugare, data_expirare) 
                VALUES ($codul_elevului, $materianote, $id_note, $data_nota, $luna_nota, $data_adaugare, $data_expirarii) ")
                or die("Hopa! Ceva nu merge!");
        echo "Adaugat cu succes!";


    }//sfarsit if isset submit 333

}//sfarsit daca sunt alese toate campurile


}
```

The problem is here: `else // daca a fost apasat submit 333`
Nothing in the else works when I press the "submit333" submit button.
I tried echoing something in the else statement, but nothing works.

Any ideas? What did I do wrong?

MySql is ok. Thanks everyone for answers!

Comment: ever heard of a thing called __loop__?

Comment: what you do wrong... to many things to answer them all...
look up: input value sanitization; why not to use the mysql_* function s in 2013; when do i really need a html table;... just to name a few...

Comment: i would like that whoever gives negative votes state why they do this. Are there too many questions? Is there a limit of questions per project? or, I do no show that i worked at this code? Thanks!

Comment: Acelasi Eu: the code style makes it very hard to read your code and give you suggestions, also you lack some generall understanding in modern concepts. on a sidenote, debuging code/variables/comments in a foreign language isnt quite easy..

Comment: it is because of the disclaimer. it gave a vibe of arrogance and generally people do not like it who are willing to help. Do not put a disclaimer like that or get ready to get downvotes. __AS for your answer__: your query in the `else` part is failing but you aren't seeing it as probably you have disabled error reporting. hence the echo does not work. __Put the echo before the query and see if it prints something__

Comment: I asked a few questions without it, and everyone started saying that i should no longer use mysql...etc. AND received negative votes. i dont know what to do...

Comment: 1. format your questions better: make an example that is as small as possible, but still showing the problem. For instance: all those options above have nothing to do with the problem. 2. state your goal, what you did and  why, what happened and what you expected. You now just dump your code, and say "nothing else works". Put in some effort to explain why you think it should work, and what you did to debug. Add errors, etc. 3. Actually ask a question. 4. no need to add thanks. 5. Read the FAQ and the info about the site (you would've guessed all of the above, so why not do this first?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is flawed.

With all the other stuff cut out, your code comes down to this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit13']))
{
}
else
{
  if(!isset($_POST['submit333']))
  {
  }
  else
  {
    // here is where you want stuff to happen when $_POST['c'] is set
  }
}
```

But if you pressed the submit button `submit333`, then you will most likely *not* have pressed the submit button `submit13` at the same time, right?

And because you *did not* press `submit13`, your code goes into the first `if` block, so it does not go into the `else` branch belonging to that first `if`, and so your second `if` is never even executed …

Comment: I`m starting to understand now. I don`t know why everybody here expects that you are a pro programmer. I am a begginer. I help whoever I can, and expect this in return. I`m no perfect. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @AcelasiEu You lack basic understanding of logic, nothing to do with programming imo. :)

Comment: @afarazit this was 4 months ago...from then, I learned zend framework, and get along pretty well ;) We all begun from this;) Peace and love!